# Assign object to variable in node.js

Tags: node.js

Could someone explain me why I can't pass the rows Object to the clubs variable?

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'test'
});
var competition_feed = 'England';
var season_id = 2014;
var clubs = {};

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * FROM clubs WHERE competition_feed=\''+competition_feed+'\' AND season_id='+season_id+';', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    clubs = rows;
});

console.log(clubs);

connection.end();
```

It seems I'm missing something about variables and scope. Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, the reason this doesn't work is because

```
connection.query(.....)
```

Is asynchronous.  So clubs isn't set to rows until later in the event loop.  Much after you are trying to use it.  One way to achieve the behavior you want is as follows:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'test'
});
var competition_feed = 'England';
var season_id = 2014;
var clubs = {};

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * FROM clubs WHERE competition_feed=\''+competition_feed+'\' AND season_id='+season_id+';', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    clubs = rows;
    logClubs();
});

function logClubs() {
    console.log(clubs);
}


connection.end();
```

Comment: Thought it had something to do with 'asynchronousity' (if that's a word) but couldn't figure out how to exactly achieve this behaviour. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`clubs = rows` is executed asynchronously. If you put a `console.log` right before `clubs = rows`, you will see it actually executes afterwards despite coming first in the code.

Comment: Beat you to it by 21 seconds :)

Comment: Congrats! :( for me though